# DataMapper - Enum like options flag for Discriminator?

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-datamapper

I have recently started using DataMapper in a few projects & overall I think its just fantastic. But I have a question about using a particular aspect of it.

I know that if I have a model with an Enum property (`property :whatev, Enum[ :foo, :bar ]`), I can call `Model.whatev.options[:flag]` & get back all of the different possible values for the particular Enum. I am wondering if anyone knows (or could point me in the right direction) if there is something similar for the `Discriminator` property type?

ie. is there a way to call that particular property & have it return the various options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but here goes. Given model definitions such as:

```
class Foo
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :type, Discriminator
end

class Bar < Foo; end
class Baz < Foo; end
```

You can see the subclasses with:

```
Foo.descendants.entries
```

which returns an array: `[Bar, Baz]`.